# Wildfly unknown error on startup

Tags: java, wildfly, linux-mint

I have a wildfly server currently running on windows, but at home i am running linux and need to setup the same server so that i can continue working on projects at home. When trying to startup the server on linux i get the following error. Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
    anon-vm bin # ./standalone.sh
    ========================================================================

    JBoss Bootstrap Environment

    JBOSS_HOME: /home/anon/Documents/werk/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/wildfly-10.0.0.Final

    JAVA: java

    JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

    =========================================================================

11:34:54,156 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
11:34:54,553 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
11:34:54,658 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final "Kenny" starting
11:34:55,431 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:131)
at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:356)
at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan
at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:155)
at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml$DefaultExtensionHandler.parseExtensions(StandaloneXml.java:126)
at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_4.readServerElement(StandaloneXml_4.java:218)
at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_4.readElement(StandaloneXml_4.java:141)
at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:103)
at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:49)
at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:123)
... 3 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:147)
... 11 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module
at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.loadModule(ExtensionXml.java:196)
at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.access$000(ExtensionXml.java:69)
at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:127)
at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan:main
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:223)
at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.loadModule(ExtensionXml.java:178)
... 8 more

11:34:55,471 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
11:34:55,628 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested.
11:34:55,697 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0050:     WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final "Kenny" stopped in 24ms
```

Comment: Have your installation's jars been shuffled or did you just update the configuration xml?

Comment: i just copied the server from windows to linux, i have never attempted this before and have 0 idea's what i am doing

Comment: Either the configuration xml was modified and left incomplete, or some module libs were removed. The best you can do is install using a fresh download.

Comment: will try that and report back thanks

Comment: It can't find the clustering module. Have a look in `$JBOSS_HOME//system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/clustering/` for the `infinispan/main` directory. Also ensure it has a `module.xml` and the JAR in there.

Comment: ended up moving away from wildfly. java in total to be honest. back to good old trusted c#